# how to get the missing values in SQL query when using in clause

Tags: sql, database

Suppose I have the following  query :

```
select value from table where value in ('abc','cde','efg');
```

If only 'abc' is populated in the table,
I want to be able to see which value is missing in the result set,
so the results looks like :

```
cde
efg
```

Comment: you didn't write which database as oracle,mysql,... and what did you tried

Comment: Creating a temporary table with those values in and joining on it might be a neat approach,  depending on your environment; if you can send multiple queries etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to get a resultset with all the values that you want:

```
SELECT 'abc' AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'cde' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'efg' FROM dual
```

(you may omit `FROM dual` depending on your database). 
And with `NOT EXISTS` get all the values from the above resultset that do not appear in the table:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (
  SELECT 'abc' AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cde' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'efg' FROM dual 
) u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t WHERE t.value = u.value)
```